# Detect any change in editor content - CKeditor 5, via javascript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I've looked at the CKEditor 5 documentation, but still can't work out how to get a simple javascript alert('hello') to fire when any balloon editor region is clicked on in my page. Any clues very much appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, as soon as an editor content region is clicked into (keydown event possibly?), I would like the alert('hello') to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the answer is actually very simple, just bind an on click event to the element, in this case via the CKEditor class, using JQuery as below:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ck-editor__editable_inline', function(e) {
// do something
})
```